# What are quarks made out of?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

I want to know what quarks are made out of for a project for my class. It has always confused on what quarks are.

Comment: Duplicate of [What are quarks made of?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16048/50583)

Comment: "We don't know, but we are still trying to find out!" is a good answer, too. The research into the structure of the physical vacuum is far from finished. Indeed, we have seen nothing, yet, is probably as good an attitude as any.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good question but hard to answer. So far experimental particle physics is concerned, no signature of quark substructure observed till date. Nevertheless imagination of a theorist goes far beyond. There are few proposal already in the literature notably the idea of **Preons**. Which was considered as the constituent particles of quarks. But its a mathematical artifact more than a physical entity.

Once it was considered Higgs as composite particle made up with top, anti-top quark, although its been ruled out. Now some physicists believe Higgs made up with a more fundamental particle called **Technicolor**. Therefore one can consider studying particle physics is like pealing the cosmic onion (as told by Frank Close).

So answer of your question is under the sky (open).