# Are quarks real particles? Or only combination form of leptons inside nucleons?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, protons, leptons

There are not any free and independent quark in the nature. Collision of many particles inside most powerful accelerators could not produced any free and independent quark but result of collision between protons are leptons (muons)and energy but not free quarks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are quarks made of?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16048/)

Comment: They are real particles in the current theory, maybe someone in the future comes up with one that agrees with your viewpoint, but I find that unlikely.

Comment: Also, notice, that for instance, in string theory, there is no such thing as real particles, they are vibrations of fundamental strings.

Comment: Protons and neutrons, in the particle picture of reality, are a tightly-bound soup of very short-lived quarks and antiquarks. If you count up everything that's there at a given time and subtract the antiparticles, you get +3, but if you named one of those 3 quarks Steve, Steve the quark would be gone and replaced by Joe the identical quark before you could say "particle physics is weird". Hope this helps.

Comment: There are no free or independent photons, electrons etc. either. Quanta are always energy exchanges between the free field and systems that we call "source" and "absorber". In quantum field theory we are required to "locate" sources and absorbers at infinity, i.e. we abstract those processes away completely anyway. The "difference" between a quark field and an electron field is that one can never find a plane wave of a single quark at infinity whereas we imagine that we can find an electron plane wave there. That is an illusion based on a naive understanding of scaling.